# Batch script to delete MQ queue

Tags: batch-file, ibm-mq

I need a sample script which will clear IBM MQ queue below script use to clear rabbit MQ queue, for example:

```
if [%1]==[] echo Queue Manager Profile was not specified && goto Usage
if [%2]==[] echo Queue Name was not specified && goto Usage

cd /D C:\Capitalware\MQBT\
mqbt.exe QLIST -p %1 -k %2 -t L -f qdepth.txt -D
```

Comment: Brackets are not the proper way to check for an empty variable. If a space or special character is assigned as a value to the variable the IF command will fail. Double quotes are the correct usage.

Comment: Is this for IBM MQ or RabbitMQ? I suspect the executable you are using is for IBM MQ

Comment: I need a script for IBM MQ

Comment: I am curious about the script in your question - the program you show is for use with IBM MQ, and yet in your question you suggest that you are currently using it to clear a queue in Rabbit MQ.

Comment: I have written an answer which shows how to clear a queue. I have just noticed however, that your question title says you want to delete a queue. Can you confirm which action it is that you need?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is about scripting MQ Batch Toolkit (MQBT) for deleting messages from a queue.  Note You could have sent a message to Capitalware Support (support@capitalware.com) for help.

The QList function of MQBT is for generating a list of queues of the queue manager.

Also, you appear to be posting only part of the script.  Here is the entire sample Windows batch file called ***ClearQ.bat***:

```
@echo off
setlocal

if [%1]==[] echo Queue Manager Profile was not specified && goto Usage
if [%2]==[] echo Queue Name was not specified && goto Usage

cd /D C:\Capitalware\MQBT\
mqbt.exe QLIST -p %1 -k %2 -t L -f qdepth.txt -D
FOR /F "tokens=1,2" %%A in (qdepth.txt) DO (

   if %%B GTR 0 (
      mqbt.exe ClearQ -p %1 -q %%A
   )
)
del qdepth.txt
goto :DONE

:Usage
echo Usage: %0 QMgr_Profile_Name Queue_Name
goto :DONE

:DONE
endlocal
```

So, to run it and clear the contains of a single queue called TEST.Q1 of queue manager 'MQA1', you would do:

```
ClearQ.bat MQA1 TEST.Q1
```

So, to run it and clear the contains of all queues named TEST.* of queue manager 'MQA1', you would do:

```
ClearQ.bat MQA1 "TEST.*"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
if "%1"=="" echo Queue Manager Profile was not specified
if "%2"=="" echo Queue Name was not specified

echo CLEAR QLOCAL(%2) | runmqsc %1
```